# Datatype conversion?

Tags: matlab, plot, types, matlab-coder

Given a Differential Equation in matrix form:

```
f = @(t,y) [(a*y(1) + b*y(2)); (c*y(1) + d*y(2))];
a=-2; b=-1; c=1; d=-4
```

Solutions to my differential equation problem are

```
x(t)= e^(-3t) (t+1)
y{t)= e^(-3t) *t
```

General Solution is

```
Y(t)=  e^(-3t) (xo,yo)' + t * e^(-3t) (xo-yo,xo-yo)'
```

Initial condition is (xo,yo)=(1,0)=(e;g)

Matlab Code:

```
syms xSol ySol  ran with and without this statement with same error msg
t=-1.1:0.1:2.1;
plot(t,xSol)  error occurs here
hold on
plot(t,ySol)
hold off
```

Error message:

```
Error using plot
Data must be numeric, datetime, duration or an array convertible to double.
```

Further study would indicate that xSol and ySol must be numeric numbers.
I have at initial condition (1;0);

```
xSol(t) = exp(-3*t) + t*exp(-3*t)
ySol(t) = t*exp(-3*t)
```

I need to change xSol(t) and ySol(t) to xSol and ySol without (t).
How to fix? Correction must work with complex numbers.

Examples online use fplot. Is that a better function to use in this application?
I would need to define two functions for xSolv and ySolv. My code works for generic differential equation in two variables.

Example online is

```
f = @(x) sin(1/x);
```

Assume we want to plot that between 0.01 and 1:

```
lims = [.01 1];
fplot(f, lims, '.-')
```

I tried

```
xSolvpa = vpa(xSol)
ySolvpa = vpa(ySol)
fplot(xSolvpa,[-2.1 1.5])
hold on
fplot(t,ySolvpa,[-2.1 1.5])
```

but got the wrong plot. This is disconcerting. No error is given.

How to do?

MM

Answer (score 0):

CHanging syntax corrects the error nicely and now the correct plot is plotted.

```
xSolvpa = vpa(xSol)
ySolvpa = vpa(ySol)
lims=[-1.1 1.5]
fplot(xSolvpa, lims)
hold on
fplot(ySolvpa, lims)
```